# Illustrator on saving file in older version deletes artboards

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, eps

I am trying to save Illustrator file in EPS format but for an older version. When I do so it deletes all the artboards except one. How can I keep all the artboards in my file?

Comment: Save it in PDF first and then export to EPS

Answer (score 3):

The EPS formats below CS3 do not support artboards. So to keep artboards save as CS3 or newer. Artboards in any older format than that are not possible. There is no workaround for this.